# FireBug extension to examine PHP variables

Tags: php, debugging, firebug

We have [FireSymfony](http://www.firesymfony.org) that allows one to view the Symfony, PHP variables [in a firebug panel](http://www.symfony-project.org/blog/2009/09/05/firesymfony-debugging-symfony-applications-inside-firebug), so I wonder whether there is a similar extension that allows me to view PHP variables for general PHP apps ( not just Symfony apps)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to check out [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/). It is an extension to FireBug that allows sort of an extended logging of PHP through the Firefox Browser/Firebug Console.

Probably somewhat close to what you are looking for, even though you'd still have to make specific use of it in the PHP scripts.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is part of what Symfony supports, exporting PHP variables to client side for debugging.

you see, PHP variables are located on the server, not at the client. Thus when you load the page, you won't be able to see the PHP variables from client side.

Thus if you want to debug PHP variables, you must have a way for your application to export the variables out to the client side for firebug or any other extension to debug.

In other words, it's not really possible for that to happen for ALL php applications.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [Formaldehyde](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/ajaxian/~3/NUk40bvHSGM/formaldehyde-php-debug-info-for-the-client-side) which integrates nicely with Firebug.